# Why is the nearest insertion heuristic for the TSP O(n^2)?

Tags: c++

In the nearest insertion heuristic, one of the steps is finding the closest point to any one of the points in the given subtour. I believe that implementing such a search is O(n^2). Since such a search would have to be repeated n times, resulting in an overall complexity of O(n^3) I don't know how to implement this algorithim in n^2. Can someone help explain how I would implement this heuristic in O(n^2)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: "one of the steps is finding the closest point to any one of the points in the given subtour" I may just be a simple hyper chicken lawyer, but that sounds like only O(n) to find the closest point to any point. It's not the absolute closest point of all points. Just the closest to an arbitrary one.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. I thought it had to be the absolute closest. Thanks.